# Looking to find a Regular Expression to fetch only the fields I want

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a Regular Expression to break up the Event I am tracking and then split each of these pieces of the code. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

I am collecting this in GA and would like to break this up in Data Studio. I would like to use a Regula Expression to only fetch the parts I need.

I would like to filter based on the event:

```
event category = Enrollment
event action =  UtilitySelected
and then fetch only the parts I need form the event label
```

Heres what I need to brake up in the event label:

`ip=73.155.208.187|clientid=1907637160.1561128460|zip=77024|promo=|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)|landingpage=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=|plan=Electric|rate=10.3¢ |term=12 Month Term(CNP)|email=kmagon@capitalbuildershouston.com|res-type=house|address=247 HEDWIG RD HOUSTON, TX 770246735|visits=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=`

Ideally, I would need a regular expression that would say that I am only getting Enrollment & UtilitySelected and only show the rate and hide everything behind it.

```
rate=10.3¢
```

The issue is that I don't know how to drill down based on that two element and hide the data after the field I want.

Don't know if I'm explaining this correctly. Please feel free to ask questions.

Comment: You can access the rate with this `(rate=[^|]+)`, but I dont see category or action data in your content :/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a combination of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
str.split("|").filter(x => x.startsWith("rate="))[0].trim();
```

Split on a pipe `|`, filter the array where the string starts with `rate=` and get the first value. Then use trim to remove the spaces.

```js
let str = `ip=73.155.208.187|clientid=1907637160.1561128460|zip=77024|promo=|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)|landingpage=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=|plan=Electric|rate=10.3¢ |term=12 Month Term(CNP)|email=kmagon@capitalbuildershouston.com|res-type=house|address=247 HEDWIG RD HOUSTON, TX 770246735|visits=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=`;

str = str.split("|").filter(x => x.startsWith("rate="))[0].trim();
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can likely design a simple expression that would extract those desired values, such as:

```
category\s*=\s*([^\s]+)|action\s*=\s*([^\s]+)
```

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/ADCUSd/1/)

For extracting the rate, I'm not quite sure what might be desired, we can likely start with this expression:

```
(?=.*plan=.*|)(rate=[^\s]+)(?=.*)
```

and enforce our boundaries to it.

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/hvMVmu/1/)

#### TEST

```js
const regex = /(?=.*plan=.*|)(rate=[^\s]+)(?=.*)/gm;
const str = `ip=73.155.208.187|clientid=1907637160.1561128460|zip=77024|promo=|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)|landingpage=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=|plan=Electric|rate=10.3¢ |term=12 Month Term(CNP)|email=kmagon@capitalbuildershouston.com|res-type=house|address=247 HEDWIG RD HOUSTON, TX 770246735|visits=https://www.constellation.com/content/constellation/en/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77024&promoCode=
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```